# ASP.Net Core При попытке обработать Post запрос возвращает 400

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

Следую руководству с статьи [Передача параметров в Razor Pages](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/29.4.php) пытаюсь реализовать передачу параметров POST запросом. Создаю в модели метод OnPost с нужными параметрами

```
public void OnPost(string name, int age)
{
    Message = $"Имя: {name}  Возраст: {age}";
}
```

При открытие страницы с передачей параметров сайт выдает 400, не взирая на то, что включена отладка и если происходит ошибка - должен выдать сообщение о исключении. В отладочном выводе сообщение о поступившем POST запросе появляется. Кроме того, есть пометка о том, что запрос неудачный: "success":false

> Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured):
>   {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Request","time":"2018-06-22T19:51:42.8782150Z","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1","ai.operation.id":"2d5e9204-426fd30dac34dcf3","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.operation.name":"POST
>   /auth","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"DESKTOP-Q8TI744","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.nodeName":"DESKTOP-Q8TI744"},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"|2d5e9204-426fd30dac34dcf3.","name":"POST
>   /auth","duration":"00:00:00.0230074","success":false,"responseCode":"400","url":"http://localhost/auth","properties":{"AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","httpMethod":"POST","DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вместо метода OnPost создать OnGet, то все заработает...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как обработать POST запрос?

Код страницы можно посмотреть [тут](https://pastebin.com/mjXbAKLp)

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста исходный код страницы

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH Точно такой же, как по ссылке

Comment: пожалуйста, перенесите код по ссылке прямо в вопрос

Comment: Я не особо силен в ASP но насколько я понимаю в этом фреймворке есть защита от CSFR атак и при отправке POST запросов он ожидает RequestVerificationToken очень похожий вопрос обсуждался вот тут и там есть разъяснение как решить проблему - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373229/400-bad-request-when-post-ing-to-razor-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае виновником 400 ошибки была по умолчанию включенная защита от csrf атак. Узнать о этой атаке можно по [ссылке](https://learn.javascript.ru/csrf). Но если вы разрабатываете Hello World, а не серьезный сайт, то защиту можно выключить и POST запросы заработают.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
            //Отключение защиты от CSFR
            options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
        });
    }
....
```